# group, filter and count in nested array

Tags: javascript, flatten

thanks for all your help in my recent posts! This time I got an nested array and I want to group and count them. My array looks like this:

```
var arr = [
  {
    "account": {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "worker"
    },
    "fromCountry": "TE",
    "status": "created"
  },
  {
    "account": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "worker"
    },
    "fromCountry": "TE",
    "status": "pending"
  },
  {
    "account": {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "worker"
    },
    "fromCountry": "TE",
    "status": "created"
  },
  {
    "account": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "CEO"
    },
    "fromCountry": "FE",
    "status": "done"
  },
  {
    "account": {
      "id": 1123,
      "name": "worker"
    },
    "fromCountry": "FE",
    "status": "created"
  }
]
```

I want to group them by Country, count the countries and save in the child the name typs and count them as well. So it has to look like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "TE",
    value: 3,
    child: [
      {
        name: "worker",
        count: 2
      },
      {
        name: "CEO",
        count: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "FE",
    value: 2,
    child: [
      {
        name: "worker",
        count: 1
      },
      {
        name: "CEO",
        value: 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

(Note: I would not like to use extra javascript libraries)

Could you help me please?

Comment: just a stupid question, does neither of all answers to all of you questions never is acceptable? maybe you have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key question beside of the grouping is here, how to get a nested property. This grouping value is taken with a helper function which checks if the given key is an array or not. If an array, then take the items as keys for the object and return a possibly found value. Needless to say, it works for an arbitrary count of groups, depending on the data set.

```js
function getGouped(array, groups) {
    function getValue(object, key) {
        return Array.isArray(key)
            ? key.reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object)
            : object[key];
    }

    var result = [],
        object = { _: { children: result } };

    array.forEach(function (o) {
        groups.reduce(function (r, k) {
            var name = getValue(o, k);
            if (!r[name]) {
                r[name] = { _: { name, count: 0 } };
                r._.children = r._.children || [];
                r._.children.push(r[name]._);
            }
            r[name]._.count++;
            return r[name];
        }, object);
    });
    return result;
}

var data = [{ account: { id: 123, name: "worker" }, fromCountry: "TE", status: "created" }, { account: { id: 3, name: "worker" }, fromCountry: "TE", status: "pending" }, { account: { id: 123, name: "worker" }, fromCountry: "TE", status: "created" }, { account: { id: 1, name: "CEO" }, fromCountry: "FE", status: "done" }, { account: { id: 1123, name: "worker" }, fromCountry: "FE", status: "created" }];

console.log(getGouped(data, ['fromCountry', ['account', 'name']]));
console.log(getGouped(data, ['fromCountry', ['account', 'name'], 'status']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to group the arrays into an object. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array. Loop thru the array using `map` and form the child property into an array.

```js
let arr = [{fromCountry:"TE",account:{name: "worker", id: 123},status:"created"},{fromCountry:"TE",account:{name: "worker", id: 3},status:"pending"},{fromCountry:"TE",account:{name: "worker", id: 123},status:"created"}, {fromCountry:"FE",account:{name: "CEO", id: 1},status:"done"}, {fromCountry:"FE",account:{name: "worker", id: 1123},status:"created"}];
 

let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  let f = v.fromCountry;
  c[f] = c[f] || {name: f,value: 0,child: {}};
  c[f].child[v.account.id] = c[f].child[v.account.id] || {name: v.account.name,count: 0}
  c[f].value++;
  c[f].child[v.account.id].count++;
  return c;
}, {})).map(o => {
  o.child = Object.values(o.child);
  return o;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your code works fine but sometime i got an undefined with c[f].child[v.account.id]